# \. in RewriteCond matches a file requested from the browser, but not relative references in the file itself

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect files in a directory to a CGI if the URL does not exist, where the URL is further processed. Since that has also consquences for non-existing files referenced inside of HTML-documents, an HTML-document can trigger an entire cascade of redirects if it contains a lot of references (imgs, css files, js files) that do not exist. Of course, in an ideal world, all of those should exist but, well...
Anyway, since I won't be using the character "." in any of the URLs I want to redirect, I thought it a pretty nifty idea to exclude file names with a "." in the RewriteCond, since that should take care of .css, .js and .gif/.jpg.
Not so lucky. If I enter a URL with a "." in the browser location, I get the (correct) message "file not found", but when I check in the server logs, every non-existent file referenced by the HTML template is passed on to the CGI, regardless of whether it contains "." or not. `css/doc.css` is processed as will be `images/bg.png` and all other files containing ".". My .htaccess file contains the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /bla
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)  /cgi-bin/env.pl?.template=Main.html&.query=$1 [PT]
```

However, after changing one of the references in the HTML-file for an external stylesheet (css/doc.css) to an absolute URL (aka /css/doc.css), it only provokes the "File not found" error, as it should according to the above rule. Is Apache not applying those regexes to relative URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all there is nothing relative when Apache receives a HTTP/HTTPS request.** Relative paths are resolved by your browser itself before sending out request to web server.

Now try changing your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bla/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /cgi-bin/env.pl?.template=Main.html&.query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava, the Options header was actually enough to do away with the problem of the interpretation of dead links within the document. My cgi parses, and works with, the QUERY_STRING and the REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING parameters, as well as the other REDIRECT_ params, so QSA is a bit overkill. The RewriteBase I was using (sans terminal /) works just fine nor do I know about case-sensitivy in `RewriteEngine On`, but the lowercase "on" I was using didn't cause any problems and that's the way of the Apache docs, so I just keep it. However, the Options did it and this is why you get my vote;-)

Comment: You're welcome, I have seen many times that these `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` is the missing trick in mod_rewrite.